# finding local maxima on the top of the terraces in 2d array

Tags: algorithm, max

As I know local maxima can be found in the derivative which is 0. however, if the 2d array is step-like, the derivative==0 would be everywhere. for example, in 1-d

case1=
[0,0,0,1,2,3*,2,1,0,0,0,1*,0,0]

the * can be found as derivative sign change before and after *,for example, 3-2>0 and 2-3<0 then the * would be a place to check. However

case2=[0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3*,3,3,2,2,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1*,1,1,0]

There would be some problems to find the * since the sign change from + to 0 and form 0 to - may be everywhere ,as well as in 2d condition.

not sure what's the key word of this kind of question,thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Since you have discrete arrays, you'd rather use a `diff` function (differences between consecutive elements) and see where the sign changes. Even in your 1D example here, I don't see how you derive the derivative around 3 (and equate that to 0). Also, what do you want to do with saddle points?

Comment: you are right, It should be sign changes. I would edit it.

Comment: Naive question: in a relatively small array (fits into memory) of an arbitrary dimension, why would you calculate derivative instead of directly finding an extreme point? Do you want to operate sparsely and skip most of the values (like in the binary search in an ordered sequence)?

Comment: yes, I would like not to scan over all elements since the array may be huge.